# Hydrogen/Remix react Styled-component App works on Chrome privalty but not normal way

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, server-side-rendering, remix, hydrogen

I am working on a React project With Hydrogen/remix framework. I installed and used styled-components and everything run good. But recently a teammate show me in his env, he can only run on private window. We found out that a google tool made this error but still, I can't solve it :p

Try to add babel configuration. donwgrade to styled-component V4 ( actual is v5)

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).